# Choosing input channel with V4L2 API

Tags: c++, input, channel, v4l2

I want to choose the input channel of my VideoCamera device. I can select it in VLC over the "Settings-Dialog". In Advanced Settings I can switch 'input' to 3 and my camera works. 
Now I want to do this in my C++ Application. I cannot find the write method to do this. At the moment my pictures are just black. I need to choose the S-Video Channel of my device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at the source code of `v4l2-ctl` which is part of [v4l-utils](http://git.linuxtv.org/v4l-utils.git). This tool is written in C++/Qt and should provide you with all information you need to do it yourself. Changing the input for a device is handled in [v4l2-ctl-io.cpp](http://git.linuxtv.org/v4l-utils.git/tree/utils/v4l2-ctl/v4l2-ctl-io.cpp?h=stable-1.8)

```
void io_set(int fd)
{
    if (options[OptSetInput]) {
        if (doioctl(fd, VIDIOC_S_INPUT, &input) == 0) {
            struct v4l2_input vin;

            printf("Video input set to %d", input);
            vin.index = input;
            if (test_ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_ENUMINPUT, &vin) >= 0)
                printf(" (%s: %s)", vin.name, status2s(vin.status).c_str());
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    // snip...
}
```

Hope this helps.

Edit:
Just found the relevant part in the official API documentation [here](https://www.linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/video.html).
They have some examples on that page how to change the video input.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much! :)